# Prevent UIButton touch event for multitouch

Tags: iphone, uiview, uibutton, touch, multi-touch

after finding out that there is a bug in the UITapGestureRecognizer ( [How to cancel button tap if UIGestureRecognizer fires?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6188997/how-to-cancel-button-tap-if-uigesturerecognizer-fires/6211922#6211922) ) I am thinking about detecting two finger taps and two finger double-taps in the touchesEnded method of my view controller.

Here is the situation, what I want to do and my problem:

Situaion: I have a UIView, managed by a UIViewController. This view contains multiple UIButtons that react to taps.

What I want: I want to react to two finger taps and to two finger double-taps on my view but also to one finger taps on the UIButtons.

Problem: Once a button is tapped (even if using two fingers on the view) the touchesEnded method on my view controller isn't called anymore.
How can I cancel button taps when more than one finger is used?

I already tried to subclass UIView and use the hitTest method, but the touches property of the event is always empty in this. Also I tried to overlay the buttons with a transparent UIView, but this also cancels the button touches.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Mark I was trying to get your example from the other day working. As it is a bug, I altered it to use a tap recognizer. It's not a true solution as you don't get a clicked effect on the button but the right button messages the `Touch Up Inside` event. You can check out those changes [`here`](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/22783696/toucheventtest.zip). See if it helps.

Comment: Thanks a ton for your repeated help, Deepak! This works in the demo project, I will now try to integrate it in my app. I solved the click effect problem by adding this to the "buttonPressed" method:

    [sender setHighlighted:YES];
    [sender performSelector:@selector(setHighlighted:) withObject:[NSNumber numberWithBool:NO] afterDelay:0.1];